# Find the sum of the sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the following sequence:

[image]

I need to find the sum of it. However I know that the sequence is not geometrical or arithmetic, therefore I don't know which formula would I use to find the sum.

I wrote a general sum equation: [image]

and I'm trying to tackle the problem this way but
this problem does not involve higher mathematics, therefore I know that there is a much more easier solution to it.

As you can see wolfram alpha app for series gave me the correct answer, but I would need the steps if possible.

Comment: Use binomial expansion of $(2-1)^{100}$

Comment: I can't believe this is so easy.. tnx @SimpleArt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}  & \sum_{n=0}^{100}2^{100-n}(-1)^n\binom{100}{n} \\ & =\binom{100}{0}2^{100}-\binom{100}{1}2^{99}+\binom{100}{2}2^{98}- \ldots +\binom{100}{98}2^{2}-\binom{100}{99}2^{1}+\binom{100}{100}2^{0} \\ & =(1-2)^{100} \\ & =(-1)^{100} \\ & =1 \end{align}$$

Please refer to [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: I will, txn for the link

Comment: @eugensunic You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \qquad \sum_{k=1}^n \dbinom{n}{k} 2^{n-k} (-1)^k = \left(2 - 1\right)^n = (-1)^n.$$

Put $n = 100$ and you're done.

Comment: You should make that for all n even....  For odd n we get -1

Comment: Good point, thank you! I edited.